# Is it possible to run multiple aggregation jobs on a single dataframe in parallel in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, pyspark, etl

Is there any way to run multiple independent aggregation jobs on a single RDD in parallel? First preference is Python then Scala and Java.

The course of actions in order of preference are -

1. Using Threadpool - run different functions doing different aggregations on different threads. I did not see an example which does this.
2. Using cluster mode on yarn , submitting different jars. Is this possible , if yes then is it possible in pyspark?
3. Using Kafka - run different spark-submits on the dataframe streaming through kafka.

I am quite new to Spark , and my experience ranges on running Spark on Yarn for ETL doing multiple aggregations serially. I was thinking if it was possible to run these aggregations in parallel as they are mostly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your broad question, here is a broad answer :

**Yes**, it is possible to run multiple aggregation jobs on a single DataFrame in parallel.

For the rest, it doesn't seem to be clear what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks ! Could you please indicate how to do that? I tried to search for the same but encountered pretty vague answers. I am sorry for not being clear about what I am asking.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't elaborate more. It's quite broad. Spark is a parallel data processing engine. I can't give a specific answer to such a broad question. Please read on how to ask question on StackOverflow, it might help you review your question.